# Can someone help me write this if/else in Jquery

Tags: php, jquery

```
   <!-- Search input -->
   <form method="post" action="query.php" id="searchform" name="search" class="search">
    <input id="inpBusiness" type="text" placeholder="Find a Business by Name" name="Business"/>
    <input id="inpLocation" type="text" placeholder="Or by a Massachusetts City/Town" name="City"/>
    <input id="btnSearch" type="submit" value="Search VetsDirectory" name="btnSearch"/><br/>
   </form>
   <hr />

   </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td>
    <!-- This is where the featured listings and search Query will load -->
    <h3 align="left">FEATURED BUSINESS LISTINGS:</h3>
    <div id="inputhere">
    <?PHP
    include 'php.php';
    ?>
    </div>
```

This is my form, upon submit, I need to check if a user used the inpBusiness or inpLocation to search. If they used location to search, I need the action to be query.php, if they used business to search I need action to be query2.php, if both or neither are used populate an error to basically say "pick one"

After this check. I need query.php or query2.php to populate where php.php is included inside the #inputhere div, I need it to clear php.php from that div, then append either query or query 2 based upon input.

UPDATE:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.5.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    var $article = null;
    $('#searchform').submit(function () {
        if ($article == null) {
            $("#inputhere").load("query.php").appendTo('.inputhere');
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

Without changing anything in my form, I am attempting to now just load the form into the div, but it is still redirecting me immediately to a new page displaying query.php, which I can see it loading it into the div right before the redirect. Any ideas?

Last one:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.5.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    var $article = null;
    $('#searchform').submit(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        if ($article == null) {
            $("#inputhere")).html('Loading...').load('query.php');
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

Its still loading the query on a separate page. As can be seen on my server @ www.masswarveterans.com

Comment: Instead of two different text fields, I'd suggest using just one, and then add radio buttons to indicate either 'Business' or 'Location'.  This would solve your both/neither problem in a user-friendly way.

Comment: or maybe a dropdown select box instead, and you don't really need to separate the two PHP files, just use the dropdown box value to select which field you wanted to search

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this is what you want:

```
$('#searchform').submit(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var business = $('#inpBusiness').val().trim();
    var location = $('#inpLocation').val().trim();

    if(
        (business == '' && location == '') // both empty
        ||
        (business != '' && location != '') // both not empty
    ) {
        alert('Pick one');
        return false;
    }

    var searchTerm = 'business';
    var action = 'query2.php';
    // The above definitions correspond to the implicit opposite of the statement
    // below. Overriding where necessary.
    if(location != '' && business == '') {
        action = 'query.php';
        searchTerm = location;
    }

    // Perform AJAX request to populate your div
    $('#inputhere').html('Loading...').load(action, {
        searchTerm: searchTerm,
    }, function(ret) {
        // If you need a callback on complete, use this.
    });
});
```

Then your PHP code, use `$_POST['searchTerm']` to help you decide what to display.

---

**Looking forward...**

Once you've worked out how to do this, you should start again and design it better. It'd be a whole lot better for your application if you only had one search script, and one place to input a search term. As mentioned in the comments, use a radio choice or a dropdown box to define which search type it should be.

If you do that, later on when you decide to add ten more types of searches you'll be able to do it easily without having to add conditions for every new type to your jQuery.

You'll just end up performing an AJAX request like this (for example):

```
$('#searchform').submit(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    if($('#search_term').val().trim() == '') {
        alert('Enter something man...');
        return false;
    }
    $('#inputhere').html('Loading...').load('search_file.php', {
        search_term: $('#search_term').val().trim(),
        search_type: $('#search_type :selected').val();
    });
});
```

Comment: Thank you for the advice, I am new to Jquery. The idea here is to allow a user to either search for a business in my database based upon the City that they are going to or to search for a business name they are looking for.

Comment: Yeah - you don't even really need to separate the logic for that. Your SQL could include both options e.g. `SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE business_name LIKE '%searchterm%' OR business_location LIKE '%searchterm%'` - kill two (or more) birds with one stone and keep your UI nice and simple.

Comment: That's actually a perfect solution, I'm a little tired been doing this all day haha. So really I just need the Jquery logic to include query.php into that div on submit

Comment: Scrowler, I added an update question in the edit can you take a look and let me know what you think?

Comment: You need the `e.preventDefault();` bit. `$('#formID').submit(E){ E.preventDefault(); // its there twice! });`

Comment: Also, remove the `.appendTo()`. `$.load()` should be called **on** the element it appends its results to, don't need to call `appendTo` as well.

Comment: Typo: `$('#inputhere')) <-----` two brackets. Check your developers console for Javascript syntax errors, etc.